# ¿Cómo adquirió "poner a huevo" el significado de "fácil"?

Tags: etimología, coloquialismos, españa, perú

Gracias a [What is the meaning of “poner a huevo” in Mexican Spanish?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/10525/5481) aprendí que no en todos los países de habla hispana la expresión "**poner a huevo**" tiene el significado que tiene en España, que es por cierto, [de acuerdo al DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KlyzyqH), la misma que en Perú:

> adj. Perú. Dicho de una tarea: Fácil de cumplir. Dicho de un precio: Cómodo de pagar.

y la opuesta al sentido de El Salvador y Uruguay:

> El Salv. y Ur. Situación o tarea difícil.

He revisado alguna de las expresiones que tienen el mismo sentido de "ponerlo muy fácil" como "[Así se las ponían a Fernando VII](http://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/el-origen-de-la-expresion-asi-se-las-ponian-a-fernando-vii/)" pero no encuentro ninguna explicación de cómo llegó la expresión "poner a huevo" a significar "ponerlo fácil" (por lo menos en España y Perú).

¿Alguien sabe cómo adquirió esta expresión ese significado?

**Nota**: entiendo que es posible que sucediese de distinta manera en cada país, ya que en otros países tiene un significado distinto (México) e incluso opuesto (El Salvador y Uruguay). Una explicación sobre cualquiera de los dos es más que aceptable. Las respuestas no necesariamente tienen que explicar cómo sucedió en ambos sitios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este es un caso muy similar al reciente caso de *poner algo tirado* o *[estar tirado](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20548/12637)*. La expresión aparece por primera vez en la edición de 1803 del diccionario:

> Á HUEVO. mod. adv. con que se pondera lo barato que valen, ó se venden las cosas.

Es decir, poner algo "á huevo" significaba ponerlo a precio de huevo. El siguiente texto del CORDE parece corroborar esta afirmación:

> *Entonces, cuando una carambola se presentaba demasiado fácil, unos decían que estaba "como se las ponían a Fernando VII", y otros que estaba a huevo. ¿De dónde habría salido este modismo para designar lo que es "fácil", lo que "cuesta poco"? Hoy que los huevos se venden por piezas y, de dos pesetas en adelante, no podemos concebir que hubo un tiempo en que tenían un precio tan bajo que, así como lo muy costoso se compraba a peso de oro, lo que costaba poco o casi nada se decía que estaba a huevo.*
>
> Julio Casares, "Introducción a la Lexicografía moderna", 1950 (España).

Tienes un ejemplo de este uso en este otro texto, algo más antiguo:

> *[...] porque ha crecido tanto el número de esta mercaduría, que la soberbia de los deseos encuentra proporcionados los apetitos; y lo demás corre tan barato, que valen a huevo los pecados mortales, y ya los más son pecadores de gorra, lascivos petardistas y lujuriosos de contrabando.*
>
> Diego de Torres Villarroel, "Visiones y visitas de Torres con Don Francisco de Quevedo por la corte", 1727-1728 (España).

Como decir que algo estaba "a huevo" significaba que era fácil de conseguir (pagando poco), la expresión pasó a usarse cuando algo era fácil de conseguir en general con un mínimo esfuerzo. Curiosamente, esta acepción que ya existía en 1950 como hemos visto en el ejemplo (e incluso antes), no entró en el diccionario hasta la edición de 2001, con el significado de "a tiro", es decir, "al alcance de los deseos o intentos de alguien". Luego poner algo a huevo es ponerlo a tiro, de modo que sea fácil de lograr u obtener.