# No porque + subjuntivo

Tags: subjuntivo, sintaxis

Las gramáticas del español dicen que el verbo en oraciones causales va con el subjuntivo, si la causa está negada. Aquí tengo un ejemplo:

> *No podemos vernos **no sólo porque** mis padres me lo **prohíben** sino porque
>   no te quiero.*

Me gustaría saber si en este caso usamos el indicativo porque la razón es real. Entonces aunque “porque” va precedido por “sólo” eso no cambia nada, ¿verdad?

Gracias.

Comment: La causa no está negada — *no solo porque X sino Y* (ojo, que ya no lleva tilde) efectivamente «además de porque X, porque Y» o «porque X y también Y».  Son todas plenamente afirmativas.

Comment: Aahh sí ahora lo veo, la palabra „solo“ hace q las razones se unan. Muchas gracias : )

Comment: @Aurora (o guifa), por qué no publicar entonces una respuesta? Parece que guifa ha dado la pista para resolver "el misterio", pero si Aurora ha encontrado una respuesta a su propia pregunta, por qué no publicar una de manera formal (cualquiera de los dos)? Mejor que el post tenga una respuesta "oficial" y aceptada que comentarios (será más útil a futuros usuarios). Aurora, responder a tus propias no solo está permitido, si no que se incluso se anima a ello (incluso con medallas, como "self-learner"). Venga, animaos alguno, si total está [a huevo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20586/5481)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal y como indica guifa en los comentarios:

> La causa no está negada — *no solo porque X sino Y* (ojo, que ya no lleva tilde) efectivamente «además de porque X, porque Y» o «porque X y también Y». Son todas plenamente afirmativas.