# ¿Por qué es diferente "valer huevo" que "valer un huevo"?

Tags: modismos, españa, colombia, locuciones

Al menos en Colombia, cuando algo *vale huevo* significa que vale muy poco, o que no es importante. Ejemplo de ello es este titular de un periodico en internet: [La investigación vale huevo](https://www.elespectador.com/opinion/la-investigacion-vale-huevo-columna-683687), donde se critica la falta de atención que hay respecto a la investigación en el país. Supongo que la analogía con el huevo se hace porque es un alimento relativamente barato.

Sin embargo, me encontré con una expresión muy parecida, que tengo ententido que es usada en España: "valer un huevo". Encontré al menos en [esta página](http://www.asihablamos.com/word/palabra/Vale%20un%20huevo.php) que significa valer mucho:

> en España
>
> Significa que es algo que cuesta mucho dinero o que cuesta mucho esfuerzo.
>
> *Quieres comprar esa casa?, no creo que te alcance, esa casa vale un huevo*

¿De donde viene el significado de valer mucho para "valer un huevo"?

Comment: Así sin buscar información, yo diría que se debe entender "huevo" aquí como "testículo": daría un testículo por tener esa casa, o para pagar esa casa tendría que dar uno de mis huevos (similar a "daría un brazo por tal cosa"). Pero no me hagas mucho caso que está demostrado que mis intuiciones fallan más que una escopeta de feria.

Comment: Pues suena muy acertado :)

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con Charlie ya que la expresión **costar un riñón** también se usa en España con el mismo significado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esa referencia a "huevo" en España es a los testículos. En España se usa mucho huevo como [sinónimo de "testículo"](https://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=43097)  aunque también hay quien indica (mismo enlace) que puede deberse al alto contenido proteínico de los huevos, que en ciertos momentos de la historia de España eran un bien muy preciado (alguna vez has oído lo de "Cuando seas padre comerás huevos"? Esto se decía porque los huevos, que era caros y valiosos, se solían reservar para el padre en las familias humildes, porque era el que tenía la responsabilidad de trabajar y obtener sustento para el resto de la familia).

Se observa mejor cuando a la expresión se le añade la coletilla "**y parte del otro**".

> Venga, que me aburro un huevo y buena parte del otro ([Menéame](https://www.meneame.net/notame/tnt80/2473702))
>
> Costó un huevo y parte del otro ([termbank](http://termbank.com/es/espanol-ingles/costo%20un%20huevo%20y%20parte%20del%20otro))
>
> Me ha costado un huevo y parte del otro ver el problema ([wordreference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/costar-un-huevo.1240864/?hl=es))

En esta última web uno de los comentarios aclara (o aventura) que el origen está en expresiones similares como "**cuesta un ojo de la cara**" o "**cuesta un riñón**", que aluden a órganos valiosos, muy queridos o incluso de elevado coste económico en el caso de un transplante.

En el caso de Colombia (y otros países) "huevo" tiene en cambio la connotación de "barato" o incluso fácil. En [¿Cómo adquirió “poner a huevo” el significado de “fácil”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20586/5481) Carlos Alejo aclara que el precio de huevo es barato, y de ahí la asociación con "fácil".

> Hoy que los huevos se venden por piezas y, de dos pesetas en adelante, no podemos concebir que hubo un tiempo en que tenían un precio tan bajo que, así como lo muy costoso se compraba a peso de oro, lo que costaba poco o casi nada se decía que estaba a huevo.
>
> Julio Casares, "Introducción a la Lexicografía moderna", 1950 (España).

Y debido a esas diferentes asociaciones (en unos países es el huevo literal y en España hace referencia al testículo) en diferentes países la expresión tiene distinto significado.